# How to resolve permission issue inside docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, file-permissions, rhel

I have created a custom docker image which is working fine on centos but not on the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo).

No uid and gid for available for the file system. so could not access any files.

```
[root@568e47d62be4 /]# ls -l
ls: cannot access 'bin': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'boot': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'dev': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'etc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'home': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lib': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lib64': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'licenses': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'lost+found': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'media': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'mnt': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'opt': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'proc': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'root': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'run': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'sbin': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'srv': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'store': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'sys': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'tmp': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'usr': Operation not permitted
ls: cannot access 'var': Operation not permitted
total 0
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? bin
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? boot
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dev
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? etc
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? home
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lib
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lib64
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? licenses
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lost+found
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? media
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mnt
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? opt
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? proc
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? root
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? run
l????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sbin
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? srv
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? store
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sys
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? tmp
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? usr
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? var
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: It depends on your customer image definition. If you create an image with system directories mapped to the host, then I can imagine different behavious on different types of Linux hosts. Maybe post your image definitied (Dockerfile) here?